# Passing the output of one transaction as input to the following transaction in jmeter

Tags: javascript, regex, jmeter

Can any one please tell me how to implement the following scenario using jmeter

Scenario consists of a Thread with four **Http** Samplers each one having a unique url
as **transaction_1**, **transaction_2**, **transaction_3**, **transaction_4**.

The **transaction_1** gets input from its url and the output of **transaction_1** is passed as input to **transaction_2**. In the same way the output of **transaction_2** is passed to **transaction_3** and from **transaction_3** to **transaction_4** as well.

My question is how to implement it in jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of 1st [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `output`
   - Regular Expression: `(?s)(^.*)`
   - Template: `$1$

     [image: JMeter Regular Expression]

   The above regular expression will store **full** response of the "HTTP Request 1" into `${output}` JMeter Variable. If you need partial response - amend the regular expression according to your needs, check out [Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) JMeterUser Manual chapter and [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) With JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter) for details
2. Use the extracted value in the "HTTP Request 2" like `${output}` where required, i.e. below example will send "HTTP Request 1" response as "HTTP Request 2" body

   [image: JMeter Variable as HTTP Request body]

See [Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) page for more information on using JMeter Variable and functions

Comment: Please go through my question again. If there are only two transactions using Reg Exp is better option my scenario contains more than two.

Comment: You can add either 3 Regular Expression Extractors to Samplers 1-3 (as children) or add a single Regular Expression Extractor (at the same level) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzI5x.png)

Comment: If script having 100 transactions and condition is previous transaction output is input to following transaction how it can be done.